# sql server replication algorithm

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, replication, date

Anyone know how the underlying replication model in sql server works? Do they essentially depend on UTC datetime values to determine if something is new or do they keep a table of all the changes (like a table of tableID+rowid that have changed).

I am building my own "replication" system and was planning on using the dates to know what to replicate. Then I started wondering what would happen if the date got off in the computer for some reason. The obvious choice is to keep a log of the changes as you go and once you replicate those changes, you remove from the log of changes. But thats a lot of extra work, instead of just checking dates.

I figure if sql server replication works by just checking the dates, then that should be good enough for me.

Any wisdom here?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has a LogReader job that is aptly named.  Replication reads the transaction log and applies appropriate transactions to the subscribing databases.

Comment: OK. So that answers my question. SQL server is handling it by essentially queuing up all the changes as opposed to looking at date modified. This makes sense because it would break down if the system date was changed. So I guess thats what I figured.

Answer (score 2):

As a transaction occurs in SQL Server, it is written to the transaction log along with information pertinent to the transaction.

SQL Server replication uses this transaction log to determine which transactions have not yet been processed and to move them to the subscriber. There is a lot more going on under the hood to keep track of the intersection between transactions, publications, subscriptions, etc. but I will leave that to MSDN documentation about SQL Server replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

**Moving on to your point about building your own replication system:**

*Do not build your own replication system.* There are too many complications involved that will cause you to spend many many days working. You will be much better off using the items that are shipped with SQL Server.

SQL Server replication methods are pretty impressive out of the box.

If you outline what causes you to think in terms of building your own replication system, we can help you figure out how to use existing items to provision what you need.

Also, read up as much as you can here to get an idea of what it can do for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: OK. Well what we have is a main server that aggregates data. We have an admin tool that loads data into it then it will send data out to all the satellites. The satellites will ask for these updates ocassionally. They also will be collecting their own data and occassionally pushing this data up to the central server. Some satellites have associations

Comment: OK. Well what we have is a main server that aggregates data. We have an admin tool that loads data into it then it will send data out to all the satellites. The satellites will ask for these updates ocassionally. They also will be collecting their own data and occassionally pushing this data up to the central server. Some satellites have associations. So satellite A and B are related. A sends its data up to the central server and it needs to come back down to satellite B. We want to avoid have GUIDs as PK so we are doing on all the satellites is creating data with SystemID (int) + IdentityID.

Comment: So when this data is copied from satellite A up to server back down to satellite B, the identity insert must be turned off during that copy. The satellites will be connected most of the time, but since it goes over the internet, obviously some times the connection will be down. I have used SQL server replication before and did not find it trivial to use out of box. It is also painful to change what you are replicating later.

Comment: We have sql server express on the satellites and standard on the main server. Also, we want all of this sent over SSL 443 and we don't want to open up any additional firewall ports. In addition, with the two part key, there is a problem if you simply copy them over to the second satellite. The second satellite will automatically up the seed to be more than the last record inserted. So we wanted to insert the copied records with negative numbers for the identity column when copying...

Comment: Raj, still think a custom solution would be inferior given the above. If so, which replication topology would you suggest to handle the above. Two things I frequently see with replication, "Don't create your own solution". Also "Don't use it if you can use a simpler method". I think my solution will be simpler, which is why I'm leaning towards it. I particularly like my solution when it comes to controlling how I handle failures in the system. Interested in another opinion if there is something obviously better. thanks.

Comment: What you have outlined seems to be a very good candidate for **Web Synchronization with Merge Replication** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx. Also Merge replication works for editions Express and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing SQLServer (and it's not the only one) supports multiple replication algorithms.
You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx) details about the ones implemented in SQLServer 2008. Read first the `X Replication Overview` then follow the `How X Replication works` for more details.